# Gradle: valid project name/path?

Tags: gradle, identifier

What characters are allowed in a project name or path in Gradle?
Is it the same as the allowed characters in a directory name for the specific OS (e.g: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filename#Reserved_characters_and_words)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Gradle does not impose any limitations on the project name with the exception of the colon (:) which is used as a path separator. For example, *my:proj* is interpreted by Gradle as a project named *proj* which is a child of a project named *my*.

Answer (score 2):

The limitations can be found [here](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/5ec3f672ed600a86280be490395d70b7bc634862/subprojects/core/src/main/java/org/gradle/util/internal/NameValidator.java#L26)

They are:  `/, \, :, <, >, ", ?, *, |`